# gcc error from easy_install of setproctitle

Tags: python, easy-install, setup.py

I'm trying to install setproctitle. I've tried just downloading the package and using setup.py to install and I've tried easy_install. Neither method works, both come up with something that looks like:

```
:~$ sudo easy_install setproctitle
Searching for setproctitle
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/setproctitle/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle/
Best match: setproctitle 1.1.2
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setproctitle/setproctitle-1.1.2.zip#md5=52f99a78cbdd1b0036bf41b4512442e7
Processing setproctitle-1.1.2.zip
Running setproctitle-1.1.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-P9lA8V/setproctitle-1.1.2/egg-dist-tmp-T0jtZK
In file included from src/spt.h:15,
             from src/setproctitle.c:14:
src/spt_python.h:14:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
src/setproctitle.c:28: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/setproctitle.c:34: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/setproctitle.c:52: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/setproctitle.c:68: error: array type has incomplete element type
src/setproctitle.c:69: error: ‘PyCFunction’ undeclared here (not in a function)
src/setproctitle.c:69: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘spt_setproctitle’
src/setproctitle.c:70: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘spt_getproctitle’
src/setproctitle.c:99: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘initsetproctitle’
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm not really sure what's going on. I've installed it easily before. I'm running a fresh installation of Ubuntu 10.04. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install the [python-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-dev) package.